# Simple has_many :through association

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

Pretty simple setup. I want to make sure my understanding of the ORM is correct.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :memberships
  has_many :groups, through => memberships
end

class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :memberships
  has_many :users, through => memberships
end

class Membership < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :group
end
```

Now when a user creates a group I want the membership record in the link table to get populated. It should be an atomic(transaction).

```
class GroupsController < ApplicationController
  def create

    @group = current_user.groups.build(params[:group])

    if @group.save
      flash[:notice] = "Group has been created."
      redirect_to @group
    else
      flash[:alert] = "Group has not been created."
      render :action => "new"
    end
  end
end
```

This doesn't work. The group gets saved but no membership record created in the link table. However using a create vs build works. Is that how it's supposed to work?

What's the best approach here?

Comment: You have a typo in the @group.save line, ( the if should not have an @ at the beginning)

Comment: Yes, that was just an error pasting it. The question still remains.

Comment: could you paste your view's code?

Answer (score 0):

This behaviour is by design. As you mentioned, you can either do `@group = current_user.groups.create(params[:group])`.

Or you can add an additional statement to create a record in the join model's table as :

```
@group = current_user.groups.build(params[:group])
if @group.save
   @group.memberships.create(:user_id => current_user)
   # redirect and notify
```

Well, the reason being simply building `@group` and saving it does not add an additional record in the join table.

Infact, in this case, `@group = current_user.groups.build(params[:group])` is somewhat similar to `@group = Group.new(params[:group])`. The difference being, in the former case, `current_user.groups` will contain `@group` (you can try that in `Groups#create` before redirect) but doing `current_user.reload` followed by `current_user.groups` will yield `[]`.

The best way to do this is somewhat similar to your approach. Have a simple create action as :

```
def create
   @group = Group.new(params[:group])
   # if else for save and redirect
```

However, for this to work the params hash submitted to `Groups#create` should include user_ids as :

```
"group"=>{"name"=>"new group", "user_ids"=>["1", "2", "3"]}, "commit"=>"Create Group"
```

May be that was the reason why @bruno077 was asking you to paste your view's code, so as to get an idea on user_ids params being passed.

So, if the new group form contains fields to select multiple users, then its simple create action as shown right above (because of the user_ids params). But if have a new group form with no options to select users, then you are better off using the first option (one using create).

Comment: only params being passed in are group[name] & group[description]. The crux of the question is if there is an inherent asymmetry in build vs create as far as associations go.

The problem with if @group.save; #create membership;

is that it's not atomic, if the membership fails you are left with an orphaned group.

Comment: Also the create with Group.new won't help at all even if there is a form with multiple users because the association is never used at all. It will never be a simple create action like the one above.

Comment: Yea, the problem with creating a group then creating a membership is atomicity, as they are two entirely different transactions. However, I  presume there shall be no such problem using create, i.e. `current_user.groups.create(params[:group])` as its a single transaction. If the join model validation leads to failure in creating a record in the join table, then the transaction rollbacks. So, there shall be no group unassociated with a membership.

Comment: "Also the create with Group.new won't help at all even if there is a form with multiple users because the association is never used at all". I don't get this. What do you mean by the association never being used ?

Comment: I meant with Group.new and then doing a save you still need to create each membership association. So that doesn't help atomicity. Unless you do a Group.transcation block.

Comment: I am sorry but I guess that's not the case. With params containing user ids, and `@group = Group.new(params[:group])` then `@group.save`, there's no need to create each membership association. With the associations defined as stated, Rails will do the required insertions in the join table. And if any validation prevents creation of `@group` or any record in the memberships table, the transaction rollbacks and there shall be no unassociated records. I don't see a problem with atomicity there. 
I guess you are not referring to insertions in multiple tables as not helping atomicity, are you ?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by params containing user ids. Group doesn't have any user ids. That's the whole point of the membership link table. And if you do Group.new and then save. The link record won't get created for precisely the same reason that it doesn't for the build case.

Comment: Well you can look at `collection_singular_ids` here http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_many . 
And then you can search around to get more into it. Here's another post on it too http://erniemiller.org/2010/10/02/the-underused-collection_singular_ids-method/ .

Comment: The code in your post is has_many :groups, through => memberships. I hope thats a typo, since it should've been has_many :groups, :through => :memberships. Check for that and finally try doing ` Group.create!(:name => "new group name", :user_ids => [1,2]) `. Be sure to have user with id 1 and 2 before hand. If this works, then Group.last.user_ids and Group.last.memberships.map(&:user_id) should equal to [1,2]. Good luck !